How to replicate "Always On" for Azure Web App behind Front Door?
Azure Web Apps have the option for "Always On".
From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal: "When Always On is turned on, the front-end load balancer sends a GET request to the application root every five minutes. The continuous ping prevents the app from being unloaded."
However, what if the Web App is not accessible publicly, and access is only via Azure Front Door? How can such an app also be "Always On" and prevented from being unloaded?
Thanks

I guess the Health probes in Azure Front door will help you achieve a similar result.
The front door will send a health probe every 30 seconds by default which will prevent the backend-app from sleeping?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/health-probes
